# FabricJS - Scrolling canvas using the same scroll as the window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm creating an app that take a screenshot of the the body by using Html2canvas library. After taking the screenshot I show it in a canvas component by using fabricJS framework. This canvas will have the same height and width of the body. My issue is that I need to scroll through the canvas as if I were in the page. I've been trying with some code like this http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/f3u5r/ but it actually adds a scroll to the div that contains my canvas, but I need to use the same div as the window, otherwise I will have two scroll bars.

This is the code of my canvas

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%" id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="fbcanvas" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"; position:relative;></canvas>
</div>


#canvasContainer {
display: none;
z-index: 1000000;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Thanks

Edit:

This is how it looks now,

[image]

So when I scroll with the canvas scroll I scroll through the canvas. When I scroll with the window's canvas I scroll through the page. I need to use the scroll from the window but for scrolling through the canvas, not the window.

Comment: Have you tried `overflow: none`?

Comment: I tried with overflow: hidden, but it does not scroll

Comment: 1) Perhaps I do not understand correctly, but is that not your goal? That is: to intercept normal scrolling and translate the canvas instead. 2) And yes, I meant `hidden` instead of `none`, thank you for catching that.

Comment: Hmm I edited the topic, I hope you can understand what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't overcomplicate it.

You shouldn't be adding percentage-based dimensions for canvases anyway. From your photo above, it seems your canvas has a fixed size (based off whatever is being printed on it through fabricjs).

If your canvas (or any block element) is bigger than the screen size, the browser will add scrollbars. That's its job.

Get rid of all your styles and just let the browser do it's thing.

```
<div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="fbcanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

-

```
#canvasContainer { /* nothing */ }
#fbcanvas { /* nothing */ }
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/egb1je6m/1/

[image: JSFiddle screenshot]